# Random boot failure "cryptsetup: lvm not available" (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, luks, ubuntu-16.04

My desktop machine randomly fails to boot Ubuntu 16.04 with the splash screen showing `cryptsetup: lvm not available` when I would normally expect the prompt for the passphrase for the root partition. I set up a LUKS volume with the Ubuntu installer and LVM is not even used. Before, the system has been booting successfully for a few month by now. At first I thought the problem was caused by kernel updates not creating the initramfs properly but that is not the case. Searching for the error only brings up folks that messed up their `/etc/crypttab` or something similar.

I am actually not expecting that anyone has a straighforward solution, but I would appreciate some advise how to debug/locate the failure. So far, the log files in `/var/log` do not seem to include useful information.

PS: Some suggested to increase `rootdelay`. Does the delay even start before the LUKS volume has been unlocked?